# (Flask) SqlAlchemy after_insert event listener with rollback inside causes TransactionClosed error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables `A` and `B`.
I need to create some rows in table `B` (with `ForeignKey` reference), after I create a new row in table `A`. But if I get exception in event listener I need to make rollback for executed code inside listener. How can I do it?

For example:

```
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    ...

class B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'b'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('a.id'), nullable=False, index=True)
    ...

@event.listens_for(A, 'after_insert')
def after_insert_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    transaction = connection.begin()
    try:
        ...
        connection.execute(B.__table__.insert(), a_id=target.id, ...)
        transaction.commit()
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        # need rollback here if i got exception inside my code
        transaction.rollback()
```

Next, in my code i have somethin similar:

```
a = A(some_field='foo')
db.session.add(a)
db.session.commit()
```

This code leads me to `ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed` (this was when I closed conn inside listener) or `InvalidRequestError: This transaction is inactive`

Please, help me what I do wrong? I think with this code I'll get nested transaction, but as I understand only one transaction performs from `session.commit()` to the end of listener.

Some info about after_insert listener:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert

if it can make a difference, I use `Flask-SqlAlchemy` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the exampe code you gave in the after_insert_listener is bad, you are going the wrong way about it: instead using a listener to insert `B` instances, just let [`sqlalchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) handle this for you by defining a [`relationship`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) between `A` and `B`:

```
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    ...
    b_s = relationship("b", backref="a") # @note: new code

...
a = A(some_field='foo')
b1 = B(some_b_field='some value')
a.b_s.append(b1)
db.session.add(a)
#db.session.add(b1) # @note: no need for this, as b1 will be added 
                    # automatically due to relationship with "a" added above
db.session.commit() # @note: this will insert A and then all Bs 
                    # related to it with correct `a_id`
```

Comment: The relationship is not working for me, because I simplify my example, and in listener I do much more work in loop with FKs (one-to-many). And I can't do linking as in your example at creation time, because I don't know some fields values (None on those time), they are filling later in background celery task.